# Склонение фамилии Шкабара!

Tags: склонение

Есть семья: Иван и Татьяна, а фамилия у них Шкабара. Правильно ли употребить «семья Шкабара», не склоняя?

Answer (score 1):

Да, вполне, по аналогии с "семейство Йохансон".

И при склонении фразы будет затронуто только первое слово, как "в городе Москва".

Если же нужно сказать в отношении, например, главы семейства, т.е. "в семье Ивана Шкабара(ы)", то это вопрос изученный (http://www.oshibok-net.ru/for-all/sklonenie-famili/).

Comment: Так каков же ответ?